# How do you translate this phrase in English- だからVってなんやねん

Tags: translation, japanese-to-english

How do you translate this phrase in English

> だからVってなんやねん

Comment: Would you be clearer about which part you don’t understand? Is it だから, って, or なんやねん? And is that V supposed to be placeholder for a verb? Do you have a concrete example to share?

Answer (score 2):

なんやねん is a Kansai dialect, and the meaning in this sentence is "What is... ?"

This sentence means: "So, what is V?"

Comment: 日本人の方ですかな？I made some changes to your post. So English text should be quoted using "" instead of 鉤括弧（「 」）

Comment: I learned something new！thank you！☺